# Recover deleted encrypted home dir after Ubuntu install over partition

Tags: 12.04, data-recovery, ecryptfs

I had an encrypted home dir in my Ubuntu partition (system and home together). I left the live usb plugged in and someone reinstalled Ubuntu over that partition.

I read all I could on the net about people with similar issues. First of all, I stopped using the affected hard drive (writing this from a Lubuntu live cd). Then I ran Photorec on the affected disk, without any filter (i.e. recover everything). The results are now sitting in an external disk.

Among all the files, I think it's the .eCryptfs ones I need. However, I only know my login password. I never wrote down the mount passphrase. I know I can recover it with just my login password if I find the `wrapped-passphrase` file.

However, Photorec didn't recover the original name of any file (I believe it names them according to the disk sector from which they were recovered). Moreover, all files are distributed among different directories (recup_dir.1 and so on).

Is my only choice to wade through the millions of txt files until I find `wrapped-passphrase`? I don't think I could recognize it, since most surely it's a byte stream and there might be millions of files like that...

**EDIT**: Just in case anyone was wondering, the version was 12.04 (which means the filenames were encrypted, IIRC)

**EDIT2**: I created an Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine with the same user and password as my old system and enabled home dir encryption. Here's the resulting `wrapped-passphrase` file:

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly [r-linux](http://www.r-tt.com/free_linux_recovery/) is capable of file recovery with its actual name. So use it to recover wrapped-passphrase

Comment: Can you upload/show a sample wrapped-passphrase file

Comment: @totti, I will try r-linux as soon as I can and get back to you. Also, I edited my question adding a wrapped-passphrase sample.

Comment: what about r-linux. Try `grep -inR --binary-files=text f2bbda0` from the root folder of recovered data.

Comment: Sorry I disappeared on you guys, I came down with a bad flu. I tried grepping the rescued files, didn't find anything. It seems like all the recovered files have some extension; there are no plain binary files without extension like `wrapped-passphrase`. Then I downloaded r-linux and scanned my partition. It recognized only the current partition (overwritten) and a bunch of extra found files. If I browse them, they look just like the ones Testdisk recovered. And I can only browse them by type/extension. I looked for `wrapped-passphrase` using the Find Files tool but nothing was found. Ideas?

Comment: Sorry the correct syntax is `grep -inR  --binary- files=text  f2bbda0 /path/to/recoveredData`

Comment: It found some files but none of them had the right size or extension. My only idea right now is writing a script which calls `ecryptfs-mount-private` with different passphrases until it succeeds. Might take years but I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

Since you possibly have the content of the missing wrapped-passphrase file, why don't you run a recursive grep on the files you rescued? I would suggest to start only with the first 16 characters, f...2.

GL!